# cannot access hive from spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hadoop, pyspark, hive

I am trying to install a hadoop + spark + hive cluster.
I am using hadoop 3.1.2, spark 2.4.5 (scala 2.11 prebuilt with user-provided hadoop) and hive 2.3.3 (also tried 3.1.2 with the exact same results). All downloaded from their websites.

I can run spark apps (as yarn client) with no issues, I can run hive queries directly (beeline) or via pyhive with no issues (I tried both hive-on-mr and hive-on-spark, both working fine, jobs are created by yarn and executed successfully). The only thing I cannot do is access hive tables from spark.

spark 2.4.x prebuilt with user-provided hadoop is not built with hive, so I downloaded from maven the required jars (spark-hive, hive-jdbc, hive-service, thrift, ...) and put them in the classpath. I have also compiled spark 2.4.5 with -Phive, but with the exact same results as the maven jars:

1. access hive directly:

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark-hive").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    spark.sql("show tables").show()
```

after all the requires jars are in classpath, spark session is created successfully, but on calling "show" on a query, I get this error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.sql.
: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_STATS_JDBC_TIMEOUT
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.formatTimeVarsForHiveClient(HiveUtils.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
```

I am trying to access hive as an external catalog, with these settings:

```
spark.sql.catalogImplementation     hive
spark.sql.warehouse.dir             /user/hive/warehouse
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version    2.3.0
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars       /lib/hive/*
```

2. access hive via jdbc

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark-hive-jdbc").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("url", "jdbc:hive2://hive:10000/default").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("user", "hive").option("password", "hive").option("fetchsize", "512").option("dbtable", "bank_csv").format("jdbc").load()
df.show(10)
```

Since hive-jdbc connector seems to be missing from the prebuilt hive distribution, I am downloading the jar from maven. After that, the query results in all fields being populated with the column names:

```
>>> df.show(10)
+------------+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
+------------+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
|bank_csv.age|bank_csv.job|bank_csv.marital|bank_csv.education|bank_csv.default|bank_csv.balance|bank_csv.housing|bank_csv.loan|bank_csv.contact|bank_csv.day|bank_csv.month|bank_csv.duration|bank_csv.campaign|bank_csv.pdays|bank_csv.poutcome|bank_csv.y|
+------------+------------+----------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+----------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

If the table has non-string defined columns, it will give errors about not being able to convert the data (since it gets only strings).
As you can see, I am using the `fetchsize` option as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843241/spark-jdbc-returning-dataframe-only-with-column-names

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Using the Cloudera JDBC driver (`com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.HS2Driver`) works.

Comment: you will need to register HiveDialect, here is a blog post about it: https://medium.com/@viirya/custom-jdbc-dialect-for-hive-5dbb694cc2bd
in short, the Spark SQL use the default JdbcDialect, which quote the column name with double quote, but hive is expecting backtick for quote column name, double quoted string is treated as a constant